# How can I merge a list and a data extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions

How can I merge Email and status from a list and data extension into another data extension?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot leverage SQL in conjunction with lists.

Hence, the only way is via export (from list)/ reimport (into a DE that mirrors your list). Then you can compare / join two DEs using SQL.

If your usecase needs to be automated, you can leverage the "data extract" activity, which places files in the "safehouse", which just means a non-public space on the sFTP, and import from there.

Now it gets a little jumbly, but this is how it works without exposing the file on the "frontend" (sure, password-protected) part of the FTP where you might not want your PII to go just for a basic operation like this.

for this, you need to make the safehouse a file location of type "Safehouse" in setup. Call it "mySafehouse" or whatever, so we don't get confused.

After the list extract (which always drops in safehouse), even though we don't want to move our file anywhere else, you STILL need a file transfer of your file to your file location "mySafehouse".
Only THEN you can reimport the contents by specifying as source "mySafehouse".

So:

- Extract List (to safehouse)
- File transfer csv from safehouse to "mySafehouse" (file location)
- Import csv from "mySafehouse" (file location) to Data Extension
- SQL operations

As terrible as this setup is: performance is high, data is not surfaced, and I've heard this approach actually be recommended, by Salesforce, when you just need to move data from one container to the next.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this with SQL in Automation Studio. Just have it update the DE. You will need to match the primary keys and non-nullable fields:
Select
l.SubscriberKey,
l.EmailAddress,
l.ListName,
l.ListType,
l. [Status],
l.CreatedDate as CreatedDate,
l.DateUnsubscribed,
l.SubscriberKey as AcctId,
l.SubscriberKey as AccountId,
l.SubscriberKey as ContactId,
l.EmailAddress as PersonEmail
from [_ListSubscribers] l
where ListName = 'Your Lists Name' and l. [Status] = 'active'